# How to take NSDictionary's name/key and store it in a NSString in a plist?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to take the name of a dictionary, or in other word they key of a dictionary and store it in a NSString. For example:

```
<dict>
<key>dictionary1</key>
<dict/>
<key>string1</key>
<string></string>
<key>string2</key>
<string></string>
<key>dictionary2</key>
<dict/>
<key>string3</key>
<string></string>
<key>dictionary3</key>
<dict/>
<key>string4</key>
<string></string>
```

`

I want to take dictionary1 and dictionary2 and store it in a NSString that look like this: @"dictionary1" and @"dictionary2". Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get NSString values for keys in an NSDictionary by using either [`allKeys:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeys) or [`allKeysForObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeysForObject%3a)

These come back as arrays of NSStrings.

There's also a [`keyEnumerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keyEnumerator) method, which allows you to step through all the keys of a NSDictionary object.

Comment: I don't want the keys of the value inside the dictionary, but rather the key of the dictionary itself.

Comment: from what I can tell, the two dictionaries in your example up there are part of an *array* (there is an "`<array>`") thing starting them off... but no closing "`</array>`" bit... is this from a plist?

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. Please read my original post again. Thank you.